# Chrome Linux --kiosk printing

Tags: linux, google-chrome, kiosk

I am setting up a kiosk (Linux/GNU, Debian) that requires silent printing from the browser.  I may just end up using Firefox, but already have chrome installed and was wondering if the --kiosk printing argument worked or not?

I tried it and I still have to hit the print button to get rid of the print prompt...

Comment: Yup, is not working under linux.

Answer (score 0):

Old one, but just confirming that the following works

```
$ google-chrome random.txt --kiosk --kiosk-printing
```

on

```
Ubuntu 16.04  
Google Chrome 51.0
```

Answer (score 0):

On new Firefox 71 Currently in Beta you could also do `--kiosk`

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/#nightly